# What is more efficient when loading dataset tables?

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, stored-procedures, dataset

Is it more efficient to load all dataset tables at once (during the forms initial load) or is it better to hit the database multiple times when needed?

For example, I have a grid control and above it is two check boxes that say load ALL and Load Current. Should I load both of those SQL select statements into one dataset during the initial load. Then change the binding the grid control to the different tables that were loaded at the initial form load during the CheckedChange event?

OR

Would it be better to hit the database and load the different tables during the CheckedChange event each time?

Thanks,

Comment: None of the above, probably.  If Current is a subset of All, then Load all and when they click current, apply a `RowFilter` to filter the results using almost the same text you would have used in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Plutonix, it is a subset of the all. I will definitely do what you suggested. I was trying to test it out both ways in visual studio 2015 and look at the duration it takes to load the dataset both ways but I have no idea how to do such a thing. I just upgraded so I might need to do some more digging in that area. Thank you for your input though :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are retrieving a lot of data read-only try a routine like this one:

```
Function GetDataTable(ByVal SQL As String, Optional ByVal ConnectString As String = "", Optional ByVal SingleRow As Boolean = False) As DataTable ' returns read only Datatable
    Try
        If ConnectString.Length = 0 Then ConnectString = g.OISConnectString()
        Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectString)
            Dim rdr As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, con)
            If SingleRow Then
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow Or CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Else
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            End If
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Load(rdr)
            rdr.Close()
            Return dt
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, , "GetDataTable")
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

It uses a Datatable w/o going through the Dataset overhead.

If "Current" is a subset of the rows you have already retrieved create a Dataview from the Datatable and then use the view as the data source for the grid. Change the Dataview filter to view the "Current" records.

Comment: That function is inefficient in many ways... Also posting code doesn't help in this case as it doesn't really address the OP concern.

Comment: Inefficient - how? I'd like to know because I use this routine all the time to load multiple 1000's of rows for searches and I'd like to get better performance if I can.